# Como crear matriz global de tamaño variable en C++

Tags: c++

necesito crear una matriz que pueda ser accedida desde cualquier función pero que sea dinamica para poder tomar el valor de numero de filas del usuario, actualmente la función main esta así:

```
int main()
{

    int numero_empleados;
    cout << "Ingrese el numero de empleados: ";
    cin >> numero_empleados;
    char opcion;

    string empleados_info_basica[numero_empleados][5];
    string empleados_info_laboral[numero_empleados][4];

    cout << "Que desea hacer?" << endl;
    cout << "1. Diligenciar información básica de los empleados." << endl;
    cout << "2. Diligenciar información por labor de los empleados." << endl;
    cin >> opcion;

    switch (opcion)
    {
    case '1':
        for (int i = 0; i < numero_empleados; i++)
        {
            ingresar_datos_basicos();
        }

    case '2':
        if (sizeof(empleados_info_basica) == 0)
        {
            cout << "No existe información basica de empleados";
        }
        else
        {
            ingresar_informacion_laboral();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Y estas son las dos funciones que se llaman en el switch:

```
void ingresar_informacion_laboral()
{

    float horas_extras, descuento_prestamos, ahorro_voluntario, descuento_ss;

    cout << "Ingrese las horas extras del empleado: " << endl;
    cin >> horas_extras;
    cout << "Ingrese el descuento por prestamos: " << endl;
    cin >> descuento_prestamos;
    cout << "Ingrese el ahorro voluntario del empleado: " << endl;
    cin >> ahorro_voluntario;
    cout << "Ingrese el adescuento por seguridad social del empleado: " << endl;
    cin >> descuento_ss;
}

void ingresar_datos_basicos()
{

    string cedula, nombre, telefono, cargo, salario_basico;

    cout << "Ingrese la cedula del empleado : " << endl;
    cin >> cedula;
    cout << "Ingrese el nombre del empleado: : " << endl;
    cin >> nombre;
    cout << "Ingrese el numero de telefono del empleado: " << endl;
    cin >> telefono;
    cout << "Ingrese el cargo del empleado: " << endl;
    cin >> cargo;
    cout << "Ingrese la cedula del empleado: " << endl;
    cin >> salario_basico;
}
```

Intente crear la matriz de manera global para que pueda ser accedida de cualquier función pero no al crearla vacía asi: `string ejemplo[][]` me sale el error:

> una matriz no puede tener elementos de este tipo

Como podría hacerlo de manera que pueda agregar un array a la matriz al llamar a la función, ya sea asignandole a cada posición de la matriz un valor o alguna función parecida a array.push() en javascript o array.append() en python.

Comment: En C++ `string` no es un tipo primitivo. Puedes consultarlos [aquí](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types). Lo que si existe es STL, una biblioteca estándar con funciones implementadas. Entre ellas, [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string). Otra cosa, los arreglos deben ser de un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación. Para arreglos de tamaño variable necesitas usar memoria dinámica o alguna estructura que lo haga por ti. Por ejemplo, [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver que `std::string` no sea un tipo primitivo? [igualmente puedes crear arreglos con ellos](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E3OScxL//9fOTMvOac0JVXBJjO/uKQoNTHXjgshBhTJzEu34@LKzCtRyE3MzNPQ5Krm4iwuSbGygsgpJEYbGhjEWqMKaiUp2CrkpZYrIAnC1KWk5qSWpEbHKiQBOUWpJaVFeQoG1ly1//8DAA "C++ (clang) – Try It Online").

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster que necesitas escribir `#include <string>` para poder usarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes tener matrices sin tamaño, esto:

```
tipo ejemplo[][];
```

No lo aceptará ningún compilador. Las matrices deben tener un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación<sup>1</sup> o su tamaño debe ser deducible en base a su inicialización... **excepto** las formaciones<sup>2</sup> multidimensionales en que sólo está permitido deducir la primera dimensión:

```
// Error, no se sabe cuántos elementos tiene cada dimensión.
tipo mal0[][] = {};
// Error, no se sabe cuántos elementos tiene la segunda dimensión.
tipo mal1[10][] = {};
/* Correcto, se deduce como tamaño cero elementos en la primera dimensión
   y cada elemento de esa dimensión tiene 10 elementos. */
tipo bien[][10] = {};
```

Si quieres que la primera dimensión sea dinámica deberás usar memoria dinámica (`new` y `delete`):

```
using string5 = std::string[5];
using string4 = std::string[4];

string5 *empleados_info_basica = nullptr;
string4 *empleados_info_laboral = nullptr;

int main()
{
    int numero_empleados;
    cout << "Ingrese el numero de empleados: ";
    cin >> numero_empleados;
    char opcion;

    empleados_info_basica = new string5[numero_empleados];
    empleados_info_laboral = new string4[numero_empleados];

    ...

    delete[] empleados_info_basica;
    delete[] empleados_info_laboral;
```

Pero yo directamente abandonaría esa idea, simplemente usa contenedores estándar:

```
using info_basica_t = std::array<std::string, 5>;
using info_laboral_t = std::array<std::string, 4>;
using empleados_info_basica_t = std::vector<info_basica_t>;
using empleados_info_laboral_t = std::vector<info_laboral_t>;

empleados_info_basica_t empleados_info_basica;
empleados_info_laboral_t empleados_info_laboral;

int main()
{
    int numero_empleados;
    cout << "Ingrese el numero de empleados: ";
    cin >> numero_empleados;
    char opcion;

    empleados_info_basica.resize(numero_empleados);
    empleados_info_laboral.resize(numero_empleados);

    ...
```

---

###### <sup>1</sup>Una variable (como por ejemplo `numero_empleados`) no es un valor conocido en tiempo de compilación.

###### <sup>2</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

Comment: el corrector de vscode me da este error: "espacio de nombres "std" no tiene ningún miembro 'array'". No será 'vector' ?

Comment: [Es `std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Incluye su cabecera: `#include <array>`.

Comment: Listo, ahora si me funciona, muchas gracias!